supabase self-hosted resumable upload problem
I'm hosting Supabase with Kong and using TUS for resumable file uploads. My goal is to ensure that all client-side requests consistently start with https://myhost.com/storage/v1/..., and have Kong handle routing to the correct storage service endpoint without modifying the origin URL across subsequent requests.
My Setup:

I have a Coolify server that is running my Supabase with Kong.

The initial request to https://myhost.com/storage/v1/upload/resumable routes correctly to the Supabase storage service, and Kong successfully forwards it.

However, the second request changes the origin to https://myhost.com:8000/upload/resumable/<token>,


My client uppy config:
const supabaseUploadURL = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL}/storage/v1/upload/resumable`;
const upp = new Uppy({
      restrictions:{
        allowedFileTypes: ['.pdf', 'application/pdf'],
      }
    })
      .use(Tus, {
        endpoint: supabaseUploadURL,
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${session.user.supabase_token}`,
        },
        chunkSize: 6 * 1024 * 1024,
        allowedMetaFields: ["bucketName", "objectName", "contentType", "cacheControl"],
      });

=> docker compose of the supabase on coolify is the default one
I tried hosting supabase outside of coolify by using nginx but same issue.
